# Merging two pictures

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, image-editor

Is there a tool in Ubuntu to automatically merge two images having a common strip? I need to scan a large image, which will not fit at once in the scanner. I was thinking about scanning it in two parts and hand-editing the result in Gimp to join them. But probably an automatic tool can do the same more quickly and better.

**EDIT** I think I may have not made my point clear. My difficulty is not aligning two images. My problem is that one has to compensate for the rotation or distortion introduced by the manual process of putting the sheet into the scanner, and an automatic tool should obtain more precise results at analyzing common patterns in the two images to rotate and align them seamlessly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally settled for Hugin. It requires some manual intervention, but has produced a really good result.

[Here is a tutorial](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/scans/en.shtml) that explains how to use Hugin so that it will not try to deform your flat images (the tool was born to produce panorama images from single pictures, hence it usually compensates for the perspective effects).

Comment: why don't you accept this?

Answer (score 43):

Using the tools provided with [**ImageMagick**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

[image: Install via the software center]

We can easily join, i.e. "montage" images into one large image with the following command

```
montage -geometry 500 image1 image2 [...] output
```

See the project page for many parameters of the [geometry](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) option. CAUTION: the output argument is non-optional, having just two images on argument list ends up replacing image2 without warning. In the example above all images will be scaled to a width of `500` pixels before they are joined. Adapt this value for your image sizes. In case you need to have a fixed height choose `x500` instead. The other dimension will be scaled to preserve the aspect ratio.

---

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21325493/4098390) post saying that ImageMagick has command line tool named `convert` to merge images. To join images **horizontally** **(in alphabetical order)**:

```
convert +append *.png out.png
```

To stack images **vertically**:

```
convert -append *.png out.png
```

That should be run in a terminal into the folder containing png files to join them all.

A gui for that would be:

#### a file manager context menu to join selected images.

An easy way when it comes to that is Thunar's custom actions:

To join selected images **vertically** (into one `png` file, in alphabetical order, no matter their extension) add this custom action:

```
convert -append %F joined-vertical.png
```

To join **horizontally:**

```
convert +append %F joined-horizontal.png
```

---

For a more sophisticated way to assemble images you may want to search for panorama photo  stitcher software such as [**hugin**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/hugin) [image: Install hugin]

[image: Install via the software center]

or the [**Pandora**](http://shallowsky.com/software/pandora/) plugin for Gimp.

Comment: Will montage automatically match similar parts in the two images?

Comment: Sorry, then this is not what I am looking for. The whole point of the question is finding a tool that will match similar parts in the two images automatically.

Comment: you are the best :)

Comment: @Andrea: have you found any way to solve your problem? Montage is not for you, but have a look at other command: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php

Comment: see this page to learn more about -geometer option: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry

Comment: @Ooker yes, see my answer

Comment: By default `montage` will juxtapose the images horizontally. Is there a switch to do this *vertically*? I tried `-flip`, `-flop`, `-transpose`, all to no avail...

Comment: @Andrea - I've made an edit that I think provides exactly that.

Comment: @landroni - I've made an edit that provides a way to join vertically as well

Answer (score 6):

You can easily achieve that with [Gimp](http://gimp.org).

1)Make a new file *File->New*

[image]

At the "create new image" dialog add the desired height and width.That will give you your new file which may look like this (depending on the dimensions you set) :

[image]

2)Open the two images you want to merge from *File -> Open...*

3)Then click copy at the image *Edit -> Copy...*

[image]

4)Go to the empty file you created first at step 1 and paste the images (Copy and paste the first image and then copy and paste the second) *Edit -> Paste*

[image]

5)Position the two images using the "Move" option from the Toolbox

[image]

When the pasted image is where you want it, set it in place. Either move your cursor on the canvas until you see a little anchor symbol, or click "Layer" on the Toolbar, then select "Anchor":

[image]

6)Scale the new file with the two merged pictures *Image -> Scale Image...*

[image]

Comment: This is what I was thinking to do. Then again, probably an automatic tool can do the same more quickly and better. My point is that an automatic tool should align things better than I do by hand.

Comment: I am not aware if there are any programs for such a simple thing really.But still, I am sure you cannot be THAT lazy..it won't take you more than 5 minutes :)

Comment: The point is not laziness. Putting the big sheet into the scanner produces two images that are slightly rotated, and I need to compensate for that. Doing that by hand so that the result is seamless is not so easy

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully joined jpg's into panorama by using a program called fotoxx. It has a tool for just that purpose under the toolbar "Combine"

Comment: Aha. Now how can I install and use that program? Is there any procedure?