# How do I join two images together?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, image-editor

I want to join two image files in Ubuntu 12.04.  Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Is there any utility for joining image files, perhaps something like MS-Paint in Ubuntu?

Comment: see also here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/166751/merging-two-pictures

Comment: Also see https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83446/gimp-how-to-combine-two-images-side-by-side/145543#145543

Answer (score 27, accepted):

"join two images" is a quite vague description, but I'm sure you can do what you want with **Gimp**. You can install it using **Software Center** or from the command line using

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

It is probably closer in functionality of Photoshop than to MSPaint though... which is a good thing.

Here's how to do it in GIMP:

1. *File > New* ; create image bigger than both of your images to join combined.
2. *File > Open as Layers* ; open your images.
3. Use the *Move [M]* tool to arrange your images.
4. Use the *Crop [Shift+C]* tool to crop everything when finished rearranging.
5. *File > Export to...* to save your output file.

That's it! Instead of GIMP you can use [Pinta](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/pinta-12-released-image-editor.html)

Answer (score 57):

As a complement to the other answer on `imagemagick` and  considering the need for a GUI.

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21325493/4098390) post saying that ImageMagick has command line tool named `convert` to merge images. To join images **horizontally** **(in alphabetical order)**:

```
convert +append *.png out.png
```

To stack images **vertically**:

```
convert -append *.png out.png
```

That should be ***run in a terminal into the folder containing png files to join them all***.

---

A GUI for that would be:

#### a file manager context menu to join selected images.

An easy way when it comes to that is Thunar's custom actions:

To join selected images **vertically** (into one `png` file, in alphabetical order, no matter their extension) add this custom action ('Edit - Configure custom actions'):

```
convert -append %F joined-vertical.png
```

To join **horizontally:**

```
convert +append %F joined-horizontal.png
```

The same commands can be used in a `.desktop` file in `/.local/share/file-manager/actions` which adds a context menu for **Nautilus and/or PCManFM**.

Example for vertical join:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
Name=Join images (vertically)
Profiles=profile-zero;
TargetLocation=true
Icon=gthumb

[X-Action-Profile profile-zero]
Basenames=image/*;*;
Exec=convert -append %F joined-image.png
Name[en_US]=Default profile
Name[en]=Default profile
Name[C]=Default profile
```

Comment: OMG! Your convert +append has done the trick.
 I was very much in trouble to do this simple task. and pinta and gui imagemagic was not working for me. I don't know.  But you made it so simple. Thanks.

Comment: Simple and straightforward!

Answer (score 9):

You can use `imagemagick` to do this. (I am using it as well.)

First install it: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

After that look [here](http://imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append) for usage, you will find a lot of examples. The best is that you can use it from command line (integrate within a script for example).

Comment: Imagemagick has also a kind of GUI, type `display` in Terminal.

Answer (score 5):

Two images side by side:

```
convert image1.png image2.png +append joined_horizontal.png
```

Two images one above the other:

```
convert image1.png image2.png -append joined_vertical.png
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use `-resize`  if the images don't have the same width/height**

You can fix the height for all of them with the `-resize` option, e.g. to fix a 500 pixel height on two images joined horizontally:

```
convert +append image_1.png image_2.png -resize x500 new_image_conbined.png
```

Or for vertical joins, you would want to set a fixed width instead:

```
convert -append image_1.png image_2.png -resize 500x new_image_conbined.png
```

Example:

image_1.png 1067x600

[image]

image_2.png 1920x1080

[image]

new_image_conbined.png 889x500

[image]

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737061/merge-images-side-by-sidehorizontally
- https://superuser.com/questions/290656/combine-multiple-images-using-imagemagick

**How to do it interactively with GIMP**

If you need to crop/resize images interactively first, which is often the case, then GIMP is the perfect tool for it, here's a detailed step-by-step: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83446/gimp-how-to-combine-two-images-side-by-side/145543#145543

[image]

**SVGs**

ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 doesn't handle them, so see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612434/how-to-concatenate-svg-files-lengthwise-from-linux-command-line
- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137096/is-there-a-way-to-stack-two-svgs-on-top-of-each-other
- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90844/joining-together-multiple-svg-images

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that doesn't have the luxury of installing software(ex. on a work computer)...

If it hasn't been removed, **libreoffice Draw** can also do this if your preference is manual manipulation...(with me guessing what "join" truly means)

You open both instances
cut one image
paste it to the other (or both into new file)
arrange them to preference (postiton/crop/etc)
select the entire new image
right click and convert it to a bitmap or metafile
right-click and save
choose your format