# Collating multiple images into one, programmatically

Tags: photo-management

I have 41 PDF pages converted into PNGs that I need to collate as one long vertical image, in order.

I can't do this manually because I have roughly a thousand other sets of 41 images, I need to create an automated procedure.

Comment: Have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/166751/merging-two-pictures

Answer (score 1):

Install the package named imagemagick:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Now you can use the tool called `convert`:

```
convert -append input1.jpg input2.jpg inputn.jpg out.jpg
```

or you can use to append all images

```
convert -append *.jpg out.jpg
```

Comment: can I have it target a folder full of pictures

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean?!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I used

```
convert -adjoin *.jpg outputfile.pdf
```

I hope this help another users.