# Combine pictures with cat

Tags: command-line

I try to combine two pictures.

```
cat 1.png 2.png > combined.png
```

Combined.png is 1.png instead of 1+2.png

How to combine them?

Comment: By combine I suppose you want to tile them? Horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Exactly what muru said and good thing you commented because I misread the title as combine pictures of cats.

Comment: Each file will have a header section and a detail section. Your method would result in header + detail + header + detail which is a broken format. In simple terms you want header + header + detail + detail.

Comment: try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/166751/merging-two-pictures it could help